# Python. Как сделать отправку сообщения в определённое время каждый день?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Например, рассылку каждое утро, мне кажется что если использовать while, то будет сильная нагрузка при большом количестве людей включивших рассылку, или нет?

Comment: повесить программу на шедуллер какой нибудь. или использовать модуль schedule в питоне

Comment: а как ты делаешь рассылку?

Comment: Я планирую сделать рассылку погоды в ВК по подписке, обычная отправка сообщения

Comment: На асинкио есть call_at, а так while time.sleep(3600) совсем не тратит ресурсы

Comment: А если человек 50 включат рассылку, а то и больше?

Comment: https://tirinox.ru/schedule-cron-python/ как вам и сказали - инструкция по schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваше приложение это сервис, который работает постоянно (отдельный процесс), то можно использовать Python-библиотеку [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule).

Если ваше приложение что-то вроде скрипта, который нужно запускать с некоторым интервалом, вы можете использовать cron, он есть на большинстве linux-серверов. У него достаточно простой синтаксис.

Открываете расписание:

```
[user@server]$ crontab -e
```

Вставляете строчку типа:

```
*/15 * * * /home/user/script.py
```

Сохраняете. В примере скрипт будет запускаться каждые 15 минут.

Формат cron-расписания можете проверить онлайн, сервисов полно: [раз](https://crontab.cronbox.ru), [два](https://crontab.guru/), [три](http://crontab.cronhub.io/) и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Залей скрипт на сервер и повесь на него cron

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]